# Can't run debug mode in intellij idea

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin

I can't debug Junit tests in just one of my projects in intellij idea. The error i get is "Error running 'Test': Unknown error'. I was trying to rebuild project, invalidate caches. Also I can, run tests, I just can't debug them.

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Did you try deleting the `.idea` folder and re-importing the project? Deleting the `out` directory might also help.

Comment: After reimporting project everything is fine, it had to be some idea bug.